# Django почему не скачивает картинку

Tags: django, python-3.x

Есть картинка в медиа, прописал в view.py данную функцию, но когда нажимаю на закачку на странице, он открывает файл на странице поверх, с ее отображением. Помогите решить проблему, почему не скачивает? Не понимаю, что я не так сделал.

```
def get_image(request, album_id):
      photo = AlbumPhoto.objects.get(pk=album_id)
      photo_name = photo.photo_logo.name
      file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') +"/"+ photo_name
      wrapper = FileWrapper(open(file_path, 'rb'))
      response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type="image/jpg")
      response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)
      filename = "Image_%s.jpg" %(str(album_id))
      content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
      response['Content-Dispotion'] = content
      return response
```

Comment: У вас опечатка в `Content-Dispotion`

Comment: спасибо, я чет и не заметил =/

Comment: Для чего вывод статики через функцию? Задача скрыть оригинальное имя?